# Click() is not working though there's no any error but element not opening up - (Cypress automation)

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, click, cypress

last one cy.get('[data-cy=impact-area-table]').contains(impactareas.name).should('be.visible').click({force: true}); is not working though there's no any error ,it shows that it's fine and test pass but it doesnot open up the impact area ??

```
import { fillImpactAreaForm } from './utils';
import {contact, campaign, impactArea,impactareas} from '../support/commands.js';

describe('Fundraising test suite', function () {

    beforeEach(() => {
        cy.resetDb();
        cy.visit('/');
    });
it('should allow the user to create transactions', () => {
    cy.seedOrgAndLogin().then(() => {
        return cy.factoryCreate('PersonContacts', contact);

    }).then(() => {
        cy.factoryCreate('Campaigns', campaign);

    }).then(() => {
        cy.factoryCreate('ImpactAreas', impactArea);

    }).then(() => {
        cy.get('[data-cy="sidebar-Impact Areas"]').click({force: true});

        cy.reload(true);

        cy.get('[data-cy=create-impactarea]').click();

        cy.get('[data-cy=impact-area-form]').contains('Close').click();

        cy.get('[data-cy=create-impactarea]').click();

        fillImpactAreaForm(impactareas);
        cy. wait(2000);

        cy.get('[data-cy=impact-area-table]').contains(impactareas.name).should('be.visible').click({force: true});
       //cy.get('.content-scroll-wrapper.block-content').find('.content-scroll-body').contains(impactArea.name).click({force: true});

    });
});
```

});

[image]

Comment: cy.get('[data-cy=impact-area-table]').contains(impactareas.name).should('be.visible').click({force: true, multiple: true});
 -this click() is not working

Comment: Can you post the console logs or screenshots from Cypress time travel?

Comment: i cannot add screenshot in comment but before contains(impactareas.name) there's this request (XHR)
GET 200 /sockjs/info?cb=3s6rn2w47t and then only it search for contains

Comment: Please edit your question with sufficient screenshot/ error logs

Comment: added screenshot if you need more screenshot please let me know

Answer (score 2):

It's happening in 2 situations:

- you don't have that item in your page or the dictation is different. (mention that cypress is case sensitive for `.containt`) or maybe your item is not visible.
- you have more than one of this item. for example, you have 2 `close` in your page. it makes ambition to click on witch one. try to make it clear by adding more detail.

Comment: there's no any page opening i tried by closing the form also but no any action

Comment: after the test finished, try to click on the area that you select in your test. Is it work?
probably the click listener does not work.

Comment: If your project is public and accessible from the internet may you give the GIT address to check?

Comment: sorry its private project

Comment: As I see in your screenshot, you define a click and there is nothing after that. It's mean the Cypress should not wait for anything after that, then obviously the test will pass. also, in your screenshot your test area was on `before` state.